# Monitoring multiple ports in tcpdump

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I am trying to find a way to read multiple ports using tcpdump. Suppose I have two ports,  p1 and p2, and I want to read the traffic moving through both ports simultaneously. Is there any way to do it using tcpdump or will I have to use some other tool?

Basically I am running a proxy server which is running on some port. I want to read the traffic moving through this port as well traffic moving through port 80(HTTP).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [capture network traffic on two different ports simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309451/capture-network-traffic-on-two-different-ports-simultaneously)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
tcpdump port 80 or port 3128
```

or, alternatively,

```
tcpdump port '(80 or 443)'
```

Comment: Will all the extra ports apply for the previously defined interface? `eg.: tcpdump -i eth0 port 80 or port 8080 [...]` Or I have to select it explicitly for each port, like: `tcp -i eth0 port 80 or -i eth0 8080`? Both syntaxes working, but I'm unsure which one's correct.

Comment: The `-i` option applies to the command as a whole, so you don't need it more than once.

Answer (score 62):

if you want to filter ports based on the range then use portrange.

E.g:

> tcpdump -an **portrange** 1-25

Answer (score 7):

You can also select an interface (change -i any to -i en0 for example) and the communication protocol :

`tcpdump -i any 'udp port 1812 or tcp port 1813'`